# Need to link xcode app to username/password database on my website

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on a sample social media app in xcode just for practice. I have a website that has a sign in system. I was wondering what the most efficient way to push/pull data from my site to the app is. All I'm looking to do is make a landing page with a username and password box that would check the credentials with the website's database and either allow access to the next page if the credentials are correct, or display some output if not. Just looking for a starting point. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSURLSession delegate method

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler
```

would be one way to handle authentication. Using NSURLSession you would also be able to manage data/download tasks. Another would be to use custom NSURLRequest HTTP headers/body handle your credentials.

Have a look at

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html